# Exporting Proc from one file to another in Ruby

Tags: ruby, import, export

I have a proc defined in a file that renders an array of config :
strategy.rb :

```
Proc.new do |klass|
    [
      {
        klass: ::BlockUtils::RSpec,
        args: [ "model"],
      }
    ]
end
```

I would like to writte something like

```
   strategy = require('strategy.rb').call(Product)
```

in some other file to put into my strategy variable my configuration array. 
But require('strategy.rb') renders a boolean and not my Proc.
Is there a way to export anonymous function in ruby and to achieve this

Answer (score 2):

An anonymous function in Ruby is an object just like any other object in Ruby. So, you make it available just like any other object in Ruby: by

- assigning it to a variable that both the code that creates the proc and the code that needs the proc have access to or
- having an object that can be referenced by both the code the code that creates the proc and the code that needs the proc take care of granting access to the proc or
- any transitive combination of the two.

How do you do it with all the other objects that you create in your files? Do the same with the proc!

For example:

```
$global_variable = ->{}

CONSTANT = ->{}

SomeRepositoryObject.the_proc = ->{}

def method_returning_the_proc
  ->{}
end
# Note: this last one has different semantics, it will return a different one every time
```